# Beagle Bone Black - Error when finding update packages: sudo apt-get update

Tags: sensor, i2c, spi, imu

I am very new to using any micro controller and I wanted to use an [MPU-9250](https://moderndevice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/PS-MPU-9250A-01.pdf) sensor with the Beagle Bone to give me serial data either through I2C or SPI.
Whenever I type `sudo apt-get update`  in my terminal shell I get this error:

```
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease

Err http://repos.rcn-ee.com jessie InRelease

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://repos.rcn-ee.com jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'repos.rcn-ee.com'
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease

Err http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'repos.rcn-ee.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@beaglebone:~#
```

I really don't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possiblities here.

The most likely explanation: You haven't connected to the internet. If you have an ethernet cable plugged in (on both ends!), you should be able to run `dhcpcd eth0` to bring the interface up.

If you do, try running `ping 8.8.8.8`, to check for connectivity. If that returns something along the lines of `64 bytes from 8.8.8.8`, then it must be a DNS problem.

You can resolve *that* by adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: What would be the likely prompt if I do not have an ethernet cable connected.

Comment: What do you mean likely prompt?

Comment: Well I get this is "-bash: dhcpdh: command not found" whenever I do this without the ethernet cable. I'm just trying to make sure that this is the right prompt (I don't know another word that I can use to describe this text "prompt").

Comment: That's right, but you've misspelt the command. It's `dhcpcd`. It's useless to run the command without a cable connected though. You have no internet access, which is what's causing this.

Comment: Cool I was just making sure that I was getting the correct response.